# Gently stir fermenter before bottling?

Tags: fermentation, bottling, sediment, alcohol

When you drink a spirit and mixer with a straw sometimes you get a kick of alcohol at the end, so you keep stirring it with the straw while drinking it.

Will the different components of a brew (e.g. alcohol) be at different concentrations depending on the height inside the fermenter.

If so what methods are commonly used to get around this before siphoning into bottles?

Comment: You need a better bar tender man.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the alcohol is dispersed throughout the beer.  Indeed, the entire thing is homogenous.

Comment: That said, when bottling, I stir gently after adding the priming sugar to ensure it is mixed well.  That could remove any concerns

Comment: Except that there are no concerns about alcohol.  But mixing gently to be sure the priming is distributed is a good idea.

Comment: The entire thing is homogenous ... except for the trub / yeast cake!

Comment: Stirring the fermenter is just going to mix up the gross trub at the bottom.  You don't want mass amounts of that in your bottles.  Typically, the beer is transferred from your fermentor to a secondary bucket just before bottling so that priming sugar can be mixed in.  Even if you prime each bottle individually, I'd suggest transferring to a sanitized bucket anyways, so that you don't have to worry about filling bottles AND not disturbing the trub.

Comment: Stirring the beer risk exposing it to oxygen, which is generally bad at this point. Dissolving the priming sugar in boiling water and pouring it into the second bucket before transferring the fermented beer, solves the issue of dispersing the sugar.

Comment: Gentle stirring is no problem